# Crear nuevo array en base a un array existente

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algoritmos

me encuentro con el siguiente problema que expondré a continuación.

Tengo el siguiente `array`

```
[
    {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        "campos": [
            {
                "key1": 1,
                "key2": "value",
                "key3": "value"
            },
            {
                "key1": 1,
                "key2": "value",
                "key3": "value"
            },
            {
                "key1": 1,
                "key2": "value",
                "key3": "value"
            },
            {
                "key1": 1,
                "key2": "value",
                "key3": "value"
            },
        ],
        ...
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        "campos": [
            {
                ...
            },
            ...
            ...
        ],
        ...
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        "campos": [
            {
                ...
            },
            ...
            ...
        ],
        ...
        ...
    },
]
```

En el cual debo crear un nuevo `array` con todos los valores que se repitan más de una vez en en el otro `array` de nombre `campos`. Me explico de mejor forma, por ejemplo si cualquier objeto dentro de `campos` se repite más de una vez en todas mis listas del `àrray` se deben generar uno nuevo con ese mismo objeto.

Lo anterior es para formar un formulario dinámico en el cual `campos` serian los `inputs` y si es que más de un campo se repite se debe crear un formulario de campos repetidos para ingresar el dato una sola vez. Es por ello que necesito como "separar" los campos repetidos en otro `array`.

Intente hacerlo de varias formas pero ninguna resolvió mi problema ni mucho menos satisfago mi necesidad. Inclusive trate de usar un `contains()` para ver si existia en el nuevo array que habia creado (comparandolo con un objeto de un map) pero como era de otra instancia me daba siempre `false`. No se de que otra forma se podría llevar a cabo lo expuesto anteriormente.

Actualmente tengo este código, que no sirve de mucho...

```
const filters = filters.flat()
const generalForm = []

filters.map(filt => {
    filt.fields.map((fl, index) => {
      if (!generalForm[index]) {
        generalForm.push(fl.key)
      }
      return null
    })
    return null
  })
```

El resultado esperado es el siguiente:

```
[
  {
    // objeto repetido
  }
]
```

generar un nuevo `array` con los objetos que se repiten todas las listas del `array` `campos`

Comment: Podrias, en base al array de ejemplo, incluír cual es el resultado esperado. No me queda claro si lo que se busca que sea igual es el objeto con sus tres propiedades y valores idénticos  dentro de cada `campos` o entre los distíntos `campos`

Comment: Agregue el resultado esperado. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No se si esto es lo que necesitas, trata de usar ambos retornos de la función a ver si una o la otra te sirve:

```js
window.onload = ()=>{

    //Fusiona campos repetidos en un solo campo teniendo en cuenta si los valores de cada propiedad del objeto son iguales
    function fusionarCamposRepetidos(arrayOfObjects){

        const camposRepetidosFusionados = [{}];

        //Iteramos sobre un arreglo de objetos desde el primer elemento hasta el PENULTIMO
        for(let i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length - 1; i++){

            /*
                Obtenemos las propiedades de cada objeto que estamos comparando a manera de Array y luego ordenamos
                este array, esto es necesario para poder iterar de manera correcta ambos objetos y no saltarse ninguna
                propiedad debido a una posible falta de orden.
            */
            const keysA = Object.keys(arrayOfObjects[i]).sort();
            const keysB = Object.keys(arrayOfObjects[i + 1]).sort();
            
            //Iteramos primero sobre las propiedades del objeto actual
            for(let x = 0; x < keysA.length; x++){

                //Iteramos sobre las propiedades del objeto siguiente al actual
                for(let y = 0; y < keysB.length; y++){

                    //Si ambas propiedades son iguales quiere decir que ambos objetos contienen la misma propiedad
                    if(x === y){

                        /*
                            Si el valor actual de la propiedad actual del objeto actual es igual al
                            valor actual de la propiedad actual del objeto siguiente al actual entonces
                            ambos objetos tienen la misma propiedad y ambos objetos tienen el mismo valor
                            por lo que pueden ser fusionados.
                        */
                        if(arrayOfObjects[i][keysA[x]] === arrayOfObjects[i + 1][keysB[y]]){
                            /*
                                Iniciamos la propiedad en el objeto que esta dentro del arreglo llamado camposRepetidosFusionados
                                y le asignamos como valor de esa propiedad, el valor ya sea de el valor del objeto actual que se
                                esta comparando, el valor del objeto siguiente al actual que se esta comparando (da lo mismo).
                            */
                            camposRepetidosFusionados[0][keysA[x]] = arrayOfObjects[i][keysA[x]];
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

        }

        return camposRepetidosFusionados;

    }

    //Solo funcionara para aquellas listas de objetos que tengan el mismo nombre (en este caso la propiedad "campos"), tambien siempre y cuando
    //este campo este presente en todos los demas arreglos a comparar desde el contenedor de estos.
    function getRepeteadProperties(mainObjectName, mainObjectContainer){

        /*
            Creamos un arreglo que va a almacenar los campos repetidos sin fusionar de cada objeto con la propiedad "campos", 
            este tendra el mismo tamaño que el arreglo contenedor que contiene a cada uno de los objetos "campo".
        */
        let camposRepetidos = new Array(mainObjectContainer.length).fill({});
        let camposRepetidosFusionados;

        //Iteramos primero sobre el arreglo principal de objetos
        mainObjectContainer.forEach((object, i) => {
            
            /*
                Iteramos ahora sobre cada objeto del arreglo "campos" contenido en el objeto actual que esta recorriendo el anterior ciclo
                EXCEPTUANDO EL ULTIMO
            */
            for(let j = 0; j < object[mainObjectName].length - 1; j++){

                //Obtenemos los nombres de las propiedades del objeto actual que se esta recorriendo en campos y las del objeto siguiente.
                const keys = Object.keys(object[mainObjectName][j]).sort();
                const keys2 = Object.keys(object[mainObjectName][j + 1]).sort();

                //Iteramos sobre las propiedades del objeto actual
                for(let x = 0; x < keys.length; x++){

                    //Iteramos sobre las propiedades del objeto siguiente al actual
                    for(let y = 0; y < keys2.length; y++){

                        /*
                            Comprobamos que en ambos objetos exista la propiedad actual que se esta comprobando apartir de las
                            propiedades de cada uno, se comprueba sobre el objeto actual y sobre el objeto siguiente al actual.
                        */
                        if(object[mainObjectName][j].hasOwnProperty(keys[x]) && object[mainObjectName][j + 1].hasOwnProperty(keys2[y])){

                            //Guardamos un arreglo de todos los valores que contengan la propiedad que se esta comprobando
                            let currentMatchedValuesInJSON = Object.values(object[mainObjectName][j])
                                                             .filter(el => el === object[mainObjectName][j][keys[x]]);
                            
                            /*Guardamos un arreglo de todos los valores del objeto siguiente que contengan la propiedad que se esta comprobando*/
                            let currentMatchedValuesInJSON2 = Object.values(object[mainObjectName][j + 1])
                                                              .filter(el => el === object[mainObjectName][j + 1][keys2[y]]);
                            
                            /*
                                Si el tamaño de los arreglos anteriores es mayor a uno para ambos, entonces almacenara true,
                                de lo contrario almacenara false.
                            */
                            let valueIsRepeteadMoreThanOneTimeInBothObjects = 
                                currentMatchedValuesInJSON.length > 1 && currentMatchedValuesInJSON2.length > 1 ?
                                true :
                                false;
                            
                            /*
                                Si el valor se repite mas de 2 vecez en ambos objetos (el actual y el siguiente), procedemos
                                a la siguiente operación.
                            */
                            if(valueIsRepeteadMoreThanOneTimeInBothObjects){
                                /*
                                    Si el objeto actual y el objeto siguiente en la propiedad "x" o "y" tienen el mismo valor,
                                    entonces añadiremos la propiedad al arreglo llamado campos repetidos en la pocisión i,
                                    dentro de este objeto escribiremos la propiedad y su valor.
                                */
                                if(object[mainObjectName][j][keys[x]] === object[mainObjectName][j + 1][keys2[y]]){
                                    camposRepetidos[i][keys[x]] = object[mainObjectName][j][keys[x]];
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        });

        camposRepetidosFusionados = fusionarCamposRepetidos(camposRepetidos);

        /*
         Retorna esta variable si solamente quieres obtener un arreglo con un unico objeto que 'fusiona'
         las propiedades comunes que esten en cada uno de los arreglos campos y que ademas cumplan la condición de que
         los valores de estas propiedades en el objeto se repitan mas de una vez en cada uno de sus objetos.
        */
        return camposRepetidosFusionados;
        /*
          Retorna esta variable si quieres obtener en un arreglo de objetos con el mismo tamaño que la cantidad de arreglos "campo" que hay
          con cada una de las propiedades y valores que contiene pero tomando en cuenta solo aquellos que se repitan mas de una vez en cada
          uno de sus objetos sin fusionarlos
         */
        return camposRepetidos;
    }

    const arregloObjeto = [
        {
            campos: [
                {
                    key1: 1,
                    key2: "value",
                    key3: "value"
                },
                {
                    key1: 1,
                    key2: "value",
                    key3: "value"
                },
                {
                    key1: 1,
                    key2: "value",
                    key3: "value"
                },
                {
                    key1: 1,
                    key2: "value",
                    key3: "value"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            campos: [
                {
                    key1: 0,
                    key2: "value",
                    key3: "value"
                },
                {
                    key1: 0,
                    key2: "value",
                    key3: "value"
                },
                {
                    key1: 1,
                    key2: "value",
                    key3: "value"
                },
                {
                    key1: 1,
                    key2: "value",
                    key3: "value"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            campos: [
                {
                    key1: 0,
                    key2: "value2",
                    key3: "value2"
                },
                {
                    key1: 0,
                    key2: "value2",
                    key3: "value2"
                },
                {
                    key1: 1,
                    key2: "value",
                    key3: "value"
                },
                {
                    key1: 1,
                    key2: "value",
                    key3: "value"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    console.log(getRepeteadProperties("campos", arregloObjeto));

}
```

La explicación del código esta detallada en este, sin embargo ten en cuenta que lo único que no pude hacer bien es que la función como tal no funciona (valga la redundancia) contando cuantos campos con la propiedad "campos" tienes, si no mas bien, cuenta cuantos objetos hay en el objeto que contiene esta propiedad... es decir, esto debes adaptarlo tu para que reconozca la función en cuales de estos objetos existe la propiedad "campos" y apartir de esta hacer las respectivas modificaciones, que realmente no seria mucho... espero te sirva!

Posdata: lo que entendí fue que las dos condiciones principales eran que:

- Obtener todos los campos y valores en un nuevo arreglo de objetos.
- Estos objetos contendrán solamente las propiedades que cumplan con que el valor de la propiedad del objeto este repetido mas de una vez en cada objeto, teniendo en cuenta también los demás arreglos "campos".

Así que me base en estos parámetros para dar esta respuesta, en caso de que esto sea erróneo, por favor especificar mejor que es lo que realmente se requiere o las condiciones, esto es un tanto confuso...